# Is it possible to make laptop turn off on mouse click?

Tags: laptop, power

I want somehow to have an extra turn off functionality on the laptop. Therefore, I am asking the question how to turn off the laptop from an external source (ex. Mouse click). I have seen some suggestions which show to extend the power switch inside the laptop, but I wanted just to check whether it is possible to power the laptop on this way.

Comment: You can turn it off, but not on

Comment: How can I turn it off? I am interested on that? But of course, having mouse click functionality same pressing normal shut down button on windows!

Comment: @Sam Dufel: You can also turn it on if you have enterprise remote-management firmware...

Answer (score 2):

[Although not mentioned in your question, in the comments for your question you mention that you are running Windows —DN]

Yes, you can create a desktop shortcut that will launch a command to shut down the system. You can then click the shortcut with your mouse.

I found the following at http://my.opera.com/obiwan2208/blog/system-shortcuts :

**Suspend**

```
C:\Windows\System32\Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspendState
```

**Hibernate**

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /h
```

**Power off**

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -s -t 00
```

Answer (score 0):

While danorton's answer is probably what you are looking for, you ***can*** turn off the computer with a single mouse click.

Using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com), you can do just about anything.  This AHK script will make the middle mouse button shutdown the computer.

> MButton::Shutdown, 1